# Route a controller to namespace :admin to /admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I feel like this may be a dumb question, but it's late and my head is melting a bit.. So I appreciate the assistance.

I'm trying to map the url http://localhost:3000/admin to a dashboard controller but i'm epically failing. Maybe this isn't even possible or the completely wrong idea but anyway my routes looks like this and yes

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :dashboard, { :only => [:index], :path => '' }
  ...
end
```

and my simple dashboard_controller.rb

```
class Admin::DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  filter_access_to :all

  def index
    @schools = School.all
  end
end
```

and my view is located in views/admin/dashboard/index.html.erb

thanks for any input

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is route `/admin` to that dashboard controller, then you're overcomplicating it by namespacing it like that.

Namespacing with a nested resource like that would mean that it would be `/admin/dashboards` for the `:index` action instead of having a clean `/admin` route (and you can verify that by running `rake routes` at the command line to get a list of your routes).

**Option 1: You meant to namespace it like that**

```
# putting this matched route above the namespace will cause Rails to 
# match it first since routes higher up in the routes.rb file are matched first
match :admin, :to => 'admin/dashboards#index'
namespace :admin do
  # put the rest of your namespaced resources here
  ...
end
```

**Option 2: You didn't mean to namespace it like that**

Route:

```
match :admin, :to => 'dashboards#index'
```

Controller:

```
# Remove the namespace from the controller
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Views should be moved back to:

```
views/dashboards/index.html.erb
```

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks Robbed! Option 1 fixed me.

Comment: These only work for mapping the specific path /admin to the specific action dashboards#index. They do not also map /admin/:action to dashboards#:action.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html I prefer this

```
namespace :admin do
  root to: "admin/dashboards#index"
  resources :dashboard
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace :admin do
    root to: 'users#index' # whatever. Just don't start with /admin
    #resources :dashboards <= REMOVE THIS LINE !
end
```